# How can I add chapters to the "Works" class in my Ruby on Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to add chapters to the works class in my Ruby on Rails app. These are the columns in the works table in my database:

```
create_table "works", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.string   "title"
   t.text     "description"
   t.boolean  "complete",    default: false
   t.string   "rating"
   t.text     "content"
   t.integer  "user_id"
   t.integer  "fandom_id"
end
```

So as of right now, when uploading a new work, there is an area for the actual content. By default, that will be chapter one. How can I have each work have an array of chapters, and each chapter with their own content? Also, how could I make it so that instead of a work's show route being `get 'works/:id/' => 'works#show'` it could have the chapter number after the :id, so that the chapter number in the URL is the chapter currently being shown? Sorry if that's all confusing, please let me know if I can clarify it, or if I need to add some code lines.

Comment: Create a `Chapter` model; it'll have a `work_id`, `belong_to :work`, and `Work` will `has_many :chapters`, or something similar. Check out any tutorial on Rails associations.

Comment: @DaveNewton I thought of that originally, but wouldn't that make it so that each chapter in all of the works would have a different id?

Comment: Well yeah. Each chapter *should* have a different ID, because they're different chapters. The chapter *number* should *not* be the same as the chapter ID; chapters might be reordered etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

- create a new route `'works/:id/:chapterid' => 'works#show_chapterid'`
- add a new method `show_chapterid` to the controller
- add a new method to model that will return a portion of `content` based on `chapterid`

Also you might want to split your content into chapters in your database for performance but that is not necessary and depends on the volume of your API calls and size of the content.

Answer (score 0):

You need another model named `Chapter` which has a column `work_id`.

In your `Chapter` model add:

```
belongs_to :work
```

In your `Work` model add:

```
has_many :chapters
```

In routes, to make it RESTful:

```
get 'works/:work_id/chapters/:id' => 'chapters#show'
```

Comment: so if I have a next chapter button on one work, and the chapter ids for that work is the first chapter has an id of 5 and the second one's id is 9, would I have a way of it knowing the chapter numbers of that work for each id? So that if I click next chapter, it knows that it goes from the id 5 to the id 9?